# How to convert string to float in Google Big Query ? (SAFE_CAST is not working)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to convert a column of type string to float so that I could perform mathematical calculations like >, <, = etc on it. I tried SAFE_CAST, but it results nothing. Could anyone please help in solving this.

```
What I have:

column (TYPE STRING) 
11.2.1
11.66.3
2.56.4
11.67.7



What I need:

column (TYPE FLOAT64) 
11.2.1
11.66.3
2.56.4
11.67.7
```

I need this conversion mainly to perform mathematical comparison.

Comment: Excuse me, but what number is `11.2.1`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You can consider this as OS release versions.

Answer (score 0):

If these are essentially nested version numbers, then one approach is to normalize the values in the string so they are zero-padded.  Then regular comparisons work.

Assuming four digits is sufficient for each number, you can use:

```
select (select string_agg(lpad(cast(el as string), 4, '0'), '.')
        from unnest(split(t.val, '.')) el
       ) str
from (select '11.2.1' as val union all select '11.67.7') t
```